# databinding list of double with invariant culture

Tags: .net, cultureinfo

I happen to have a list of double in a class and databind it to a combobox.
The problem I am experiencing is that the displayed text for double has a comma instead of the dot. Ex **2,56** isntead of **2.56**.

The combo box seems to convert my doubles  to string using the application culture

I cannot just change the application culture to Invariant. Any idea how I can force doubles in my application to use the invariant culture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

doubles are just numbers.  They do not have a culture.

`ComboBox`es, on the other hand, do.  You can set it using the `ComboBox.FormatInfo` property.